# Помогите с grep

Tags: регулярные-выражения, grep, linux

Здравствуйте, У меня есть дамп mysql. С помощью grep пытаюсь найти строки, отвечающие заданному регулярному выражению. 
Например `grep --color "youtube.com/embed" dump.sql`

Но весь дамп базы данных записан в одну строоку. А дамп очень большой, и он выводит практически все. Пробую `egrep -o --color "youtube.com/embed" dump.sql`, но он выводит только "youtube.com/embed". Как можно сделать чтобы выводилось youtube.com/embed и еще соседние символы. например "src="//www.**youtube.com/embed**/ZGrvJ3m4kS8" fra"?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А места, где встречается youtube всегда имеют вид `src="..."`? Если так, то можно попробовать следующее: `grep -Po 'src=.*?youtube.com/embed.*?"'`.

Если только url интересует, то можно сделать так: `grep -Po '\byoutube.com/embed/[a-zA-Z0-9]*'` - это если строка после embed всегда буквено-числовая

**Обновление**

Так зачем выводить лишнее? Если строка после embed всегда буквено-числовая, то можно использовать следующее: `egrep -o 'youtube.com/embed/[a-zA-Z0-9]+'` - тоже выводит каждую ссылку на отдельной строке, но вариант с `grep -P` мне нравится больше

Comment: grep -Po 'src=.*?youtube.com/embed.*?"'. В этом случае он тоже выводит выводит всю строку. А одна строка равносильна 1000 строк.

Попробовал так egrep -o --color "src=\\\\\"//www.youtube.com/embed.{1,100}" grow.sql

Comment: @vitaan, так-с... Версия grep`a какая? Какой дистрибутив? Я проверил в нескольких - все работает как надо.

Вы точно grep с ключом -P используете? egrep (без ключа -P) как раз выводит всю строку (grep же каждую ссылку выводит на отдельной строке)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но я сделал чуть по другому egrep -o --color ".{100}www.youtube.com/embed.{100}" grow.sql
теперь выводит 100 символов до шаблона и после

Comment: @vitaan, так зачем выводить лишнее? Если строка после embed всегда буквено-числовая, то можно использовать следующее: `egrep -o 'youtube.com/embed/[a-zA-Z0-9]+'` - тоже выводит каждую ссылку на отдельной строке, но вариант с `grep -P` мне нравится больше